# how to lazy load images in a tab only when the tab is active?

Tags: javascript, css, tabs

I just start to learn **CSS** and **javascript**.
My site has lots of **images**, and they are different tabs.
For now I'm using **lazy** to load the images. The thing is, even though the tab is not active, the images are still loaded.

Is it possible to load the images when the tab is **active**?

Below is an example of my tab:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tab1" class="frame-tab">
  <div id="tab_title" class="tab-title" switchtype="click">
    <span class="titletext">tab</span>
      <ul class="tb">
        <liclass="a">
          <a href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;" onfocus="this.blur();" style="float:;margin-left:px;font-size:;color: !important;;">Car</a>
        </li>
        <liclass="">
          <a href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;" onfocus="this.blur();" style="float:;margin-left:px;font-size:;color: !important;;">Phone</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="tabcontent" class="tb-c">
      <div class="dxb_bc">
        <div class="particle">
          <dl class="sa">
            <dd class="m">
              <a href="1-1.html" target="_blank">
                <img src="image/nophoto.gif" file="/attachment/bfd7.jpg" style="" lazyloaded="true" _load="1" width="300" height="200">
              </a>
            </dd>
            <dt>
              <a href="1-1.html" target="_blank">dfasf</a>
            </dt>
          </dl>
          <dl class="sa">
            <dd class="m">
              <a href="2-1.html" target="_blank">
                <img src="image/nophoto.gif" file="/attachment/a34a.jpg" style="" lazyloaded="true" _load="1" width="300" height="200">
              </a>
            </dd>
            <dt>
              <a href="2-1.html" target="_blank">dfasf</a>
            </dt>
          </dl>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And due to I got some js conflict issue, I'm not able to use `jquery`...if someone can provide a solution for my question, it'll be great!

Thanks very much!

Comment: Yes ...........